# Android app TCP/IP command issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, tcp

I'm trying to make an app to control some hi-fi over `TCP` and have got the following code so far. However it come's up with errors on the line `<dataOutputStream>.write(BUFFER);`

The errors are (Each error shows up twice for some reason):

```
"BUFFER cannot be resolved to a variable"
"Syntax error on token">", delete this token"
"Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
```

**CODE:**

```
package button.test; 

import java.io.IOException;`
import java.net.Socket;`
import android.app.Activity;`
import android.os.Bundle;`
import android.view.View;`

public class ButtonActivity extends Activity {`

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override`
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.2.92", 60128);
        try{
            <dataOutputStream>.write(BUFFER);
        } catch(IOException e)
        {
            //error code
        }
    }
}
```

How I want it to work is, when I click on a button it sends a specific command. The command that I want to send is `"ISCP000000100000000701000000!1PWR010D"` to power the equipment on. However I'm not sure how to include this in the code. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably end up in doing something like this:

```
String buffer="ISCP000000100000000701000000!1PWR010D";
OutputStream os=socket.getOutputStream();
os.write(buffer.getBytes());
```

Do not forget, usually you should not be doing netowrking on the `UI-Thread` in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Start from basic of Android, how to write syntax of code for object and calling it methods.

The code line,

```
<dataOutputStream>.write(BUFFER);
```

is displayed error because there are nothing a syntax like `<dataOutputStream>`. You have to make a object of **dataOutputStream** and then write a method `write(BUFFER)` also there is not declared variable `BUFFER`. From your coding practice I suggest you to go through some basic tutorial on Android..

Look at [Simple connection example - TCP communication](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/simple-connection-example-part-ii-tcp-communication)

and [Android TCP Client and Server Communication Programming–Illustrated with Example](http://www.roman10.net/android-tcp-client-and-server-communication-programmingillustrated-with-example/)